# Is it possible to put the ternary operator inside a function call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ternary-operator

I have to sets of conditions to handle in a link_to image_tag statement - does the image exist, and does the user own it? This leads to a horrible amount of code. What I'd like to do is this -

```
link_to image_tag(image.blank? ? generic_image : image), current_user == image.user ? edit_image_path(image) : image_path(image)
```

... is it possible to do this (and the errors I'm getting are just syntax problems) or is this just not do-able?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'm pretty certain if it is you'd need to be wrapping the whole ternary operation in brackets e.g. `image_tag((image.blank? ? generic_image : image))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it might be easier to make a custom helper for yourself - something like this:

```
def link_as_image(image)
  image = generic_image if image.blank?
  path = path_for image

  link_to image_tag(image), path
end

def path_for(image)
  current_user == image.user ? edit_image_path(image) : image_path(image)
end
```

Comment: Hi Dax - it turned out the errors I had were syntax and it's doable with a ternary operator - but your answer looks good as I'm going to be doing a lot of this - cheers :)

Comment: not at all - if you can make something reusable it's usually better to do so. if it helped, please check my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible - I got this to work:

```
<%= link_to image_tag((book.cover.blank? ? 'gen_book_cover.png' : book.cover), class: "bookcover"), book.user == current_user ? edit_book_path(book) : book_path(book), class: 'nolinkystyle' %>
```

... but the approach in the answer above worked better for me cos it's much simpler to implement it in a bunch of places.